# "Could not load Shockwave flash" problem on Xubuntu 13.04 with Chrome 28.0.1500.71

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, flash

This is info from `chrome://plugins/`. It is seen that `libflashplayer.so` is used. System one, not Chrome's integrated one (`libpepflashplayer.so`).

```
Adobe Flash Player - Version: 11.2 r202
Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
Name:   Shockwave Flash
Version:    11.2 r202
Location:   /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
Type:   NPAPI
     Disable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/x-shockwave-flash   Shockwave Flash 
.swf
application/futuresplash    FutureSplash Player 
.spl
```

So system flash doesn't work, Chrome cannot load it. Here's an info about it http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html

What do I need to do to make flash work in Xubuntu 13.04 with Chrome?

**UPD**:

Chromium has the same problem too. Some people suggest to use Chromium instead Chrome and it will work fine. Don't believe. It will not.

**UPD 2**:

The interesting thing is that on Window the latest Chrome is 27...and smth. And its integrated Flash is 11.7...and smth. Ubuntu's Chrome is 28... and Flash is 11.2. And from official package repository. And doesn't work.

Comment: I had the same problem with 12.04. I tried eveything to get it to work. I couldn't get it to work with Flash 11.2. I had to download Flash 10.3, extract the `libflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`. (chrome will pick this up) You will have to uninstall flashplug-installer first or just delete the .so file listed on the code you posted

Comment: I'm guessing it's an architecture/multi-arch problem.  That's off the cuff though.

Comment: @BiggJJ, Thank you very much for your comment, now all works just fine :) What I did is just renamed the file `libflashplayer.so`. I didn't delete it, didn't uninstall `flashplug-installer` or didn't download previous versions of Flash. I just renamed the file. I think Chrome detected a file absence and switched to either its integrated one or took the one from `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` as you said. Anyway now Flash is present. Write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it as the right answer.

Comment: I don't see why you have got 11.2 in Chrome - that's really not an official Google Chrome build. Google Chrome comes with 11.7 only nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with 12.04. I tried everything to get it to work. I couldn't get it to work with Flash 11.2.

Just delete or rename the .so file  in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/`

If you are still having problems download Flash 10.3, extract the `libflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`

Comment: Flash 10.3 is really old and does not receive any security updates anymore. So I won't recommend that. Chrome's built-in Pepper-flash is at 11.7 nowadays.